# Export Firefox Speed Dial addon page

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, export

Firefox [Speed Dial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4810/) allows one to create a custom home page with "speed dial" buttons. Is there an export feature to save the page as an HTML file?

Comment: not updated for Quantum

Answer (score 2):

```
Firefox>Tools>Add-ons
Speed Dial>Preferences
Main>Actions>Export as HTML
```